# How do you setup Atom to create code output to a Terminal in vertical split screen?

Tags: python, windows-10, atom-editor

I would like to replicate this setup

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKxDnCK0NAk&feature=youtu.be

It appears the code in Atom is output to an external terminal, I like that it is in a vertical split screen view.

I have Atom editor on Windows 10 with Python installed via python.org

How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a package called platformio-ide-terminal.

Open the settings in atom and you can search for it under the install tab.

Comment: Thanks, I don't find the option to place the terminal next to the code. It stays underneath. What am I missing?

Comment: The terminal next to the code is just a separate terminal window that the instructor put next to atom on the screen. It is not a part of Atom.